# closed form of $\prod_1^n (x+k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, gamma-function, products

Is there a closed form for the product
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (x+k)
$$

I'm trying to find a nice formula for
$$
\Gamma(z+n) = f(n)\Gamma(z)
$$
for some appropriate f.

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties).

Comment: The existence of such an $f$, independent of $z$, would imply $\Gamma$ is an exponential function (it's not).  Do you want a different $f$ for each $z$?

Comment: The only closed formula is $f(n,x)=\gamma(n+x+1)/\Gamma(x+1).$

Comment: If you want to find the coefficients of the polynomial...

Comment: Have a look at the Pochhammer symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is a non-negative integer
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (x+k) = \frac{(x+n)!}{x!}
$$
Else, the product can be written as a  polynomial
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (x+k) = C_nx^n + C_{n-1}x^{n-1} + C_{n-2}x^{n-2} +\ ...\ + C_0x^0
$$
The coefficients $C_n$ and $C_0$ are trivial
$$C_n = 1$$
$$C_0 = n!$$
The coefficients $C_{n-1}$ and $C_1$ can be given by
$$C_{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^nk = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$C_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{k} = n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
The coefficient $C_{n-2}$ is given as
$$C_{n-2} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right) - \left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\right) = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right) = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2)}{12}$$

The remaining coefficients must be calculated using certain advanced techniques of combinatorics, which I'm not familiar with. My answer is incomplete as of now, but I hope that someone completes my answer in the future.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The coefficients are Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Specifically, the coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of permutations of $1,2,\dots,n+1$ which are composed of $k+1$ cycles.

Comment: Pochhammer symbol?